# NodeJS NPM does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, package, npm

Hi when I try to install a new package with the npm there comes a very strage error:

```
PS C:\dev\js\test1> npm install mysql
npm.cmd : npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:4
+ npm <<<<  install mysql
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm http GET ht...npmjs.org/mysql:String)     [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

npm

http

304
 ..

npm

http

GET
 ..

npm

http

304
 ...

npm

http

GET
 ..

npm

http

304
...
mysql@0.9.6 node_modules\mysql
ÔööÔöÇÔöÇ hashish@0.0.4 (traverse@0.6.3)
```

How can i get rid of it. I want to use it as usual.
I thought of uninstalling and reinstalling but i dont have a clue how to get rid of that ****..

please help me to repair my npm or tell me how to uninstall it or is there a way to install packages manually this might be the best way.